# How to detect scroll event from pdf.js

Tags: pdf, scroll, pdf.js

I'm essentially using the default web/viewer.html and its associated files that comes with it. I have it loaded in an iframe. How can I add an event listener to when the pdf is scrolled? Thanks for any help.

Comment: `pdfIFrame.contentWindow.addEventListener("scroll", function() {..});` ? The viewer must be on the same domain as host page.

Comment: It's still not working. Did you use it for Mozilla's pdf.js library? Thanks.

Code:
Hmm, it's still not working. Here's some relevant code:
// document.html
    <div id="document_pdf-wrapper" class="document_pdf-wrapper document_block">
    <iframe id="document_pdf-iframe" src="/document/show"  frameborder="0" width="993px" height="800px"></iframe>
    </div>
// document.js
    pdfIframe.contentWindow.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
        console.log('docver.js~Line 98 -- "aksjdfklasdjfkl": ', "aksjdfklasdjfkl");
    });

Answer (score 4):

I dug around and tested some things more and figured it out, which is pretty simple but if you're in the same bind:

```
var viewerContainer = window.document.getELementById('somePdfIframe').contentDocument.getElementById('viewerContainer') will contain the element whose scrollTop will change.
```

So if

```
viewerContainer.scrollTop + $(viewerContainer).height() == viewerContainer.scrollHeight
```

then the user has reached the bottom of the pdf iFrame.

You can also viewerContainer.addEventListener('scroll', function() {...}) to listen for scrolls in the pdf iframe.

One little thing that was tricky for me is that you should make sure the pdf iframe was fully loaded before calling this code.